# EF Core Not Loading Related Properties Even With Include

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have two related classes, Voter and Party. Party is in a one-to-one relationship with Voter, represented by properties Voter.PartyID and Voter.Party.

I set up an IQueryable like this:

```
IQueryable<Voter> voters = context.Voters.Include(v=>v.Party).Where(...)
```

that creates a subset of Voters. Later on I want to summarize the subset by Party. I do this like this:

```
var retVal = voters.Select( v => v.Party ).Distinct().GroupBy( p =>
            p,
            ( p, b ) => new ...
```

Unfortunately, 'p' -- which should be the related property Party of each individual Voter in voters -- is always null.

I don't understand why the earlier Include statement isn't "forcing" the Voter.Party property to be retrieved/defined.

I've discovered that materializing the subset of Voters before doing the GroupBy seems to force the retrieval/definition of Voter.Party. Unfortunately, doing the materialization early enough to solve the problem (I've simplified things here, the actual query logic is more involved) creates some enormous datasets.

Thoughts on how to get Voter.Party to be retreived/defined?

Comment: can you show the models code also?

Comment: Why did you use `Select` in the second statement? you can still use `Include`, Select will return the list of Parties not list of Voters with parties

Comment: Definitely the entity model (classes and Fluent configuration) is needed, as well as concrete query presenting the issue. Shortly, [mcve].